# SVN Checkout without re-copying

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

I have imported an unversioned directory into an empty SVN repository then want that same directory to be versioned but there are a lot of files and Checkout is taking a long time. is there a way to set the current set of files to be equal to the current version in repository or some similar solution?

Comment: Sounds like an exact duplicate of [How to convert an existing directory to an Svn WC w/o replacing local files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861005/how-to-convert-an-existing-directory-to-an-svn-wc-w-o-replacing-local-files)... alas, that question has not yet found a solution.

Comment: Yeah, it's the same problem as that post. Seems like there's no solution, though I've posted an answer below which means only copying the files one time, not two

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one way to do this: create an empty repository then check it out into the folder of existing files - nothing will be added or removed - then commit the files. And one tip: if you can, use the SVN protocol instead of HTTP/S as it's much faster